# Simple rust ECS with no dynamic dispatch

Tags: game, rust

I'm trying to write a minimal, high performance uncomplicated ECS for a simple game in which I have a good idea of all of the Entity and Component types from the get-go.

I want to take advantage of compiler optimisations such as inlining and others, therefore I would like to avoid dynamic dispatch.

To do this, I am using enums and macros to generate the static dispatch code, where dynamic dispatch might overwise be used.

See below for a minimal example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Health(i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Damage(i32);

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Position(i32, i32);

struct Ghost {
    pos: Position,
    health: Health,
    damage: Damage
}

struct Coin(Position);

enum Entity {
    Ghost(Ghost),
    Coin(Coin),
}

macro_rules! reg_component {
    ($entity:ident with $component:ident as $fn_id:ident, $fn_id_mut:ident for $($ty:pat => $field:expr,)+) => {
        impl $entity {
            #[allow(dead_code)]
            fn $fn_id_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut $component> {
                #[allow(unreachable_patterns)]
                match self {
                    $($ty => Some(&mut $field),)+
                    _ => None
                }
            }
            #[allow(dead_code)]
            fn $fn_id(&self) -> Option<&$component> {
                #[allow(unreachable_patterns)]
                match self {
                    $($ty => Some(&$field),)+
                    _ => None
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

reg_component!{ Entity with Health as health, health_mut for
    Entity::Ghost(g) => g.health,
}

reg_component!{ Entity with Damage as damage, damage_mut for
    Entity::Ghost(g) => g.damage,
}

reg_component!{ Entity with Position as position, position_mut for
    Entity::Ghost(g) => g.pos,
    Entity::Coin(c) => c.0,
}

fn collision_system(_entity_pos: Position, entity: &mut Entity, others: &[Entity]) {
    //test for collision and then...
    for other_entity in others {
        //If the entity has a damage component, apply the damage_system
        match other_entity.damage() {
            Some(dam) => damage_system(dam, entity),
            None => ()
        }
    }
}

fn damage_system(damage: &Damage, entity: &mut Entity) {
    //If the entity has a health component, apply the damage
    match entity.health_mut() {
        Some(health) => health.0 -= damage.0,
        None=> ()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut world: Vec<Entity> = Vec::new();
    world.push(Entity::Ghost(Ghost{pos: Position(0,0), health: Health(10), damage: Damage(10)}));
    world.push(Entity::Coin(Coin(Position(0,0))));
    
    //apply systems:
    for i in 1..world.len() {
        let (current, rest) = world.split_at_mut(i);
        let current: &mut Entity = current.last_mut().unwrap();
        //If the current entity has a position component, apply the collision_system
        match current.position().cloned() { //clone position to avoid borrow of current, so it can be mutably borrowed later
            Some(pos) => collision_system(pos, current, rest),
            None => (),
        }
        //other top level systems etc...
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong here? Shooting myself in the foot? Not actually getting any performance benefits that worth it? There's a more elegant /idiomatic alternative? Please let me know if this is a good idea.